# How can I change the constraints on a view that is a child of a ConstraintLayout programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

How can I change the constraints on a view that is a child of a ConstraintLayout programmatically in Android? I cannot find any useful documentation on this. I can't even find the source code or API docs.

Comment: we won't know till google decides to add ConstraintLayout to the official docs, which wont happen till its in a stable state. i am waiting for the same too

Answer (score 2):

The constraints set on a view are defined in `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams` -- you could get the view's layout params (`View.getLayoutParams()`), set the fiels in it to what you want and call `View.setLayoutParams()` with the modified parameters.

This will work, but yes, it might be better to wait for the official documentation :)

**Updates:** in release alpha 8 there is **ConstraintSet**

[Alpha 8 Release Notes](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/recent/constraintlayoutalpha8isnowavailable)

[Sample Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html)